# Can I still use catkin init and catkin build when I can't install python-catkin-tools?

Tags: ros, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ROS Noetic on Ubuntu 20.04. When I type `sudo apt-get install python-catkin-tools`, I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies: python-catkin-tools : Depends: python-catkin-pkg (>= 0.2.9) but it is not installable Depends: python-osrf-pycommon but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356355/can-i-still-use-catkin-init-and-catkin-build-when-i-can%27t-install-python-catkin-tools?/) by [MaxM](https://answers.ros.org/users/56385/maxm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2020-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Can I still use catkin init and catkin build when I can't install python-catkin-tools?

The straight answer to this would be *no* you cannot, seeing as `python-catkin-tools` provides the `catkin` program.

If it's not installed, you cannot run it.

However, the problem you show with `python-catkin-tools` not being installable is a known issue.

See [catkin/catkin_tools#594](https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/issues/594) where this is being tracked.

Refer to #q353113 for a work-around (note: *a workaround*, this is not a solution).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try

```
sudo apt install python3-catkin-tools
```

---

Originally posted by [Henning Luo](https://answers.ros.org/users/39365/henning-luo/) with karma: 58 on 2021-10-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2